# How to retrieve user details based on user using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I'm developing a Web based Hospital Management System, In my application every thing working fine. But here is my question is How to retrieve particular user details  when the admin select particular user in his account

```
patientid   Patient Name    DOB         Gender
PAT39539    ABC           20/12/2000    male
-------     ---           ---------     ----
-------     ---           ---------     ----
-------     ---           ---------     ----
```

Like wise **N** number of user accounts are there and respectively there info is loaded. If admin select one account he need get particular user details.how to do this through **JSP**.

Comment: Can you post code/snippet which you tried so far ?

Comment: I don't have any Idea so that I'm stuck here.. could you example reference so that I can

Comment: This https://lazicbrano.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/connect-java-application-to-database/ should help you. In this article there is method selectById which would return data against particular ID likewise you can pass your user ID and can get data for that user.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you stuck and what you've tried to achieve from your end. Since you've tagged only jsp, I'm giving some sample method which accepts userId from UI and based on that it will return the User Entity.

*Try to keep DB values in a properties file to make it handy though I'm kept it inside method.*

From UI side when a user clicks the particular user, send the userid to servlet/java part. Sample user details table,

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>User ID</th>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="GetUserDetails?userId=${user.userId}">${user.userId}</a></td>
        <td>${user.userName}</td>
        <td>${user.dob%}</td>
        <td>${user.gender}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Servlet/Java:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    String userId = request.getparameter("userId");
    String query = "SELECT userid,username from Users WHERE userid = ?";
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
    stmt.setInt(1, userId);
    ResultSet rs = stt.executeQuery();
    User userObj = new User();
    // Assumed it will return single object.
    while (rs.next()){
        userObj.setUserId(rs.getInt("userid");
        userObj.setUserName(rs.getString("username");
    }

    // Close these in reverse order of creation
    rs.close();
    stmt.close();       
    con.close();
    request.setAttribute("user", userObj); // Will be available as ${user} in JSP
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/user.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

And your web.xml looks like,

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.stackoverflow.examples.GetUserDetails</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/GetUserDetails</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Finally in your user.jsp page get values from user object directly like this, `${user.userName}`. Let me know if this helps.

Cheers..!